# Why can't I reach my flask app from my smart phone?

Tags: flask

My flask app has a router as shown below:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def testfunction():
    return("Hello world")
```

when I try to reach it from my pc (which is the host of the app) it runs up as shown below:
by typing: **http://<My_IP_Address>:5000/test**

[image]

But when I try to reach the same app from my smart phone browser, it says this site can't be reached connection timed out.

my main code snippet is as shown below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

I solved the problem from changing IPV4 Address of ethernet adapter to Wireless LAN Adapter IPV4 address. Does anyone know why was this happening? And what's the right IP address to use to enable your app listen globally

Note that I am using windows system.
This is my ipconfig result. Which IP should I use?
[image]

Comment: What WSGI Server are you using? Is it suited for development or production?

Comment: Hmm I see... Actually I didn't use any WSGI server, my bad I thought allowing the port and running the app will automatically allow it to be discovered globally.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can go to `cmd` > `ipconfig` > `IP Address`, you can get your machine's `IP Address`. Should be something like: `192.168.x.x`.

On a Mac, go to System Prefs > Network.  There, you'll see a sentence that says "Status: Connected.  Wi-Fi is connected to  and has the IP address 192.168.x.x.".

Change your `host` to that IP, then navigate to `192.168.x.x:5000` and you should connect.

After reading your edit... Your phone cannot see your ethernet adapter, as it is 2 steps away.  But it can see your computer, as both are connected to the wi-fi and see each other as siblings on the same network.

Comment: Hi I am on windows actually

Comment: Answer edited for windows: If you go to `cmd` > `ipconfig`, you can get your machine's `IP Address`.

Comment: Hmm actually I have multiple static IPV4 addresses as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBOcN.png The thing is that I get to access my flask app if both my phone and system are connected on same wifi network but not when they're different

Comment: Is your machine connected via ethernet or wifi?  Both devices have to be on the same network, so use the wifi IPv4

Comment: I see... basically what I wanted to achieve was to use my machine as a global server which could serve requests to any device. Is that possible?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-make-my-computer-a-server

Comment: I see thanks for pointing out!